# I'm executing the command at the terminal getting this error to build the product table

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a products table in my Laravel application

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users');
    });
}
```

Afterwards, I'm trying to migrate my database

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

However, I'm getting this error when migrating the products table:

> Exception trace:
>
> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `apps`.`#sql-30d4_61` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
>        C:\xampp\htdocs\LTCRUDAUT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
>
> 2   PDOStatement::execute()
>        C:\xampp\htdocs\LTCRUDAUT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

How would I fix it?

Comment: Where is the table name `#sql-30d4_61` coming from? Seems like the error is not being thrown by this migration.

Comment: I think the problem is not on the `products` table, rather it's on the other migration specifically `apps`. Can you show me the migration code of that table(`apps') bro?

Comment: @escbooster12 I agree, the problem is definitely with the other migration for the apps table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because Laravel now uses `bigIncrements()` instead of `increments()` by default for the id field in the user table migration.

For foreign keys, they have to be set to the same field size. To fix:

```
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users');
    });
}
```